# Why is flutterwave redirecting to failure page after successful payment?

Tags: javascript, php, flutterwave

I'm trying to integrate the flutterwave payment gateway in my registration website. I'm using localhost for my hosting and testing and I'm having issues with redirecting to a success page after successful payment but it only keeps redirecting to a failure page even after a successful payment.

This is the code I used:

```
    getpaidSetup({
        PBFPubKey: PBFKey,
        customer_email: email,
        customer_fullname: name,
        amount: amount,
        customer_phone: phone,
        custom_logo: "https://localhost/bnbtechonlinetrainingregistration/user/img/bnbtech.jpg",
        custom_title: "Payment for Online Digital Skills Training - Course selected: " + courseselected,
        custom_description: courseselected,
        redirect_url: "https://localhost/bnbtechonlinetrainingregistration/user/success.php",
        // custom_narration:
        currency: "NGN", 
        txref: txRef,

        onclose: function () { },
        callback: function (response) {
            flw_ref = response.tx.flwRef;// collect flwRef returned and pass to a server page to complete status check.
            console.log("This is the response returned after a charge", response);
            if (response.tx.chargeResponse !== '00' || response.tx.chargeResponse !== '0') {
                // redirect to a success page
                window.location = "success.php";
                
            } else {
                // redirect to a failure page.
                window.location = "failed.php";
            }
            x.close();
        }
    });
```

Comment: So what did the `response` you logged to the console actually look like?

Comment: Is this a question about PHP? If your PHP works, then please remove that tag. If it doesn't work as it should, then you need to explain that issue and show that code as well. But as the previous comment states, you need to share the data you're having issues with.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments, it helped in spotting out the error.

Answer (score 0):

So, I checked the response I logged in the console. I noticed word/variable mismatch in this line of code:
if (response.tx.chargeResponse == '00' || response.tx.chargeResponse == '0')

It is response.tx.chargeResponseCode instead of response.tx.chargeResponse, contrary to what I obtained from flutterwave documentation.

Problem is now solved.